# Method not allowed. Must be one of: POST - Slim Framework

Tags: php, mongodb, web-services, rest, slim

I'm trying to write a restful webservice using php + slim framework. It consists in a mongodb database of pokemons that allows clients to search infos about pokemons. First there's a html form that collects the fields of search and sends it with POST method to the server. At the server there's the code bellow:

```
$app->post('/', function(Request $req, Response $res){

    $n = $req->getParsedBody(); 

});
```

but when I run the program a get the error:

```
Method not allowed. Must be one of: POST
```

here is the server file:

```
<?php


use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$con = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$db = $con->pokemon;
$colec = $db->pokemon;

$app = new \Slim\App;

// $app->get('/', function($campo) {

//  echo $campo."<br>";


   // });


$app->post('/', function(Request $req, Response $res){

    $n = $req->getParsedBody(); 

});


$app->run();

?>
```

here is the html file:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Pokedex</title>
</head>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
<img id="img" src="../Pokemon/img/pkm.png"/>

<div id="primeiraDiv">
    <form id="formulario1" action="servidor.php" method="POST">
        <p>Pesquisar Pokemon por nome:</p>
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome">
        <input type="submit" name="botao" id="botao" value="buscar">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="segundaDiv">
    <form action="servidor.php" method="POST" name="formulario2">
        <p>Pesquisar Pokemon por tipo:</p>
        <input type="text" name="tipo" id="tipo">
        <input type="submit" name="botao" id="botao" value="buscar">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="terceiraDiv">
    <form action="servidor.php" method="POST" name="formulario3">
        <input type="submit" id="listar" nome="listar" value="Listar Todos Pokemons">
    </form>
</div>
```

how do i fix it?

Comment: Show the HTML for the form.

Comment: check out, its up there

Comment: Your forms submit to `servidor.php` but your route is `$app->post('/'`

Comment: well, so I changed th e action field to action="/", it works when i submit a search, but when a run the servidor.php alone it still shows the message

Comment: what is `servidor.php`? You need to define routes instead of creating php files.

Comment: servidor.php is the file that makes the queries in the database. Sorry but, I'm learning this architecture now, I don't know how to make routes and how it works properly

Comment: Move the code from that file into a get route like `$app->get('/'` then run the root `/`. Or give it a name if you don't want it in the root, like `/something`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you sent POST method to server in your code and the actual method that has been sent is GET. Did you request to the server via browser's URL bar? If yes, edit and resend data with your specified method. If not, download Postman for Google Chrome which is suitable for developing REST API.

Comment: Explain your answer